# How can I link to another website in React?

Tags: reactjs, anchor

I have these div cards with some information, and I would like to insert a link inside them, that redirects to another site. It didn't work with `<a></a>`. can anybody help me?

Thanks!

```
import React from "react";

function Card(props) {
  return (
      <div className="card">
        <img className="img-logo" src={props.img} alt="image_logo" />
        <h3 className="name"> {props.name}</h3>
        <p className="paragraph"> {props.description}</p>
        <a href={props.link}>Page</a>
      </div>
  );
}

export default Card;
```

Comment: What is the value of `props.link`? What do you mean by "didn't work"?

Comment: Tangentially related, but personally, I'd quote the property values to avoid things breaking in potentially unexpected ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<Link>` component from `react router`.

If you are opening the `url` in new tab, make sure to use `noopener` and `noreferrer` so that the browser does not attach the current website's `window` variable to the newly opened url in the new tab, which can be a security loophole.

```js
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export const openInNewTab = (url) => {
  const newWindow = window.open(url, '_blank', 'noopener,noreferrer');
  if (newWindow) newWindow.opener = null;
};

function Card(props) {
  return (
      <div className="card">
        <img className="img-logo" src={props.img} alt="image_logo" />
        <h3 className="name"> {props.name}</h3>
        <p className="paragraph"> {props.description}</p>
        <Link href="#" onClick = {() => openInNewTab(props.link)}>Page</Link>
      </div>
  );
}
```